# AdWords Reports into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to use an AdWords script to Export AdWords Reports into BigQuery -

I have BigQuery project with enabled BigQuery API: http://prntscr.com/g8peb5

And I use correct Project ID in the script: http://prntscr.com/g8peup

But when I try to run the script, I encounter an error:

> "Access Not Configured. BigQuery API has not been used in project
>   333669768108 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   console.developers.google
>   com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/overview?project=333669768108
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry. (line 135)"

The fact is that I do not have a project with a similar ID (333669768108) and the link provided does not work correctly.

Why can there be such a problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I couldn't find a way to let the AdWords Script using BQ API run under an existing project in the Google Developer Console. Somehow AdWords needs to create a separate project for each script using [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). I had a similar issue as well with Gmail API in a script tied to Google Sheets workbook.

I am not sure what you mean with the link from the log not working correctly. Do you get a message like this one when you open it?

> The API "bigquery.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

If so, you can just click on 'Library' in the panel on the left-hand side, and activate BigQuery API from there. When you run the script next time, it should push the data to BigQuery without any problems (assuming the script is correct).